# Cloning jqGrid table (with subgrid inside) using getGridParam showing strange result

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Basically i have first jqGrid which has a subgrid inside

```
jQuery("#FirstGrid").jqGrid({ 
...
subGrid: true,
...
});
```

and i'm trying to clone/copy the first Grid into another page(grid) using

```
var gridconfig = $("#FirstGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam');
$("#SecondGrid").jqGrid(gridconfig);
```

The problem is the "SecondGrid" showing 2 columns of subgrid clickable column

Is this a jqGrid bug or did I miss something ?

Update :

found possible root cause by printing "gridconfig"

```
colModel":[
....
{"name":"subgrid","width":20,"sortable":false,"resizable":false,"hidedlg":true,"search":false,"fixed":true,"title":true,"hidden":false,"widthOrg":20},
....
], // first subgrid column added
```

and

```
"subGrid":true //another subgrid column added
```

Comment: @PiyushSardana not yet, still stuck with this

Comment: temporary solution :`$("#SecondGrid").remapColumns(*your permutation here*);` to show real subgrid column and hide another additional subgrid column

Answer (score 0):

solved using :

```
$("#SecondGrid").remapColumns(*your permutation here*);
```

it is basically shifting the columns